# Node.js async module gets finished before the iteration completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, rss, feed

I have around 100 Rss links that need to be fetched every 3 minutes.

So I am using async module to do it. But before all the Rss links are processed it finishes and exits.
Below is the Code.

**feedRecords** is an array that contains **RSS url** and a id;

```
var items = [];
var parseRss = require("parse-rss");
var async = require('async');

async.forEach(feedRecords, function taskIterator(feedItem, callback) 
{
    parseRss(feedItem.url, function (err, articles) 
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            callback(err);
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("Feed Id : " + feedItem.feed_id + ", Length : " + articles.length);
            items.push({ data : articles, feed_id : feedItem.feed_id });
            callback(null);
        }
    });
},
function ()
{
    if (items.length > 0) 
    {
        console.log("Total : " + items.length);
    }
    else
        console.log("No data found");
});
```

Immediately I get **No Data found** and then I get the log results.

Below is the output

```
No data found

Feed Id : 12, Length : 3

Feed Id : 14, Length : 1

Feed Id : 13, Length : 1

Feed Id : 17, Length : 8

Feed Id : 4, Length : 11

Feed Id : 5, Length : 7

Feed Id : 6, Length : 8

Feed Id : 16, Length : 24

Feed Id : 11, Length : 11

Feed Id : 3, Length : 18

Feed Id : 1, Length : 183
```

Can someone please solve and confirm is this the correct procedure to parse around 100 Rss feed links and store it in MySQL db every 3 minutes without duplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like one of your feeds dosn't get parsed correctly thus returns an error. 
This is a perfectly normal behavior for async.each, infact you should notice that if the iterator passes an error to its callback, the main callback (for the each function) is immediately called with the error, so if one of the functions returns an error the other callbacks won't finish executing.
If you want all the array elements to be processed anyway, you could always pass null to your callback, and find another way to take care of the errors.

Comment: Thanks bokor,
actually the err had the value **no articles** so it was causing problem.
Can i run around 5 to 10 parallel so that it does the job faster.

Comment: if you want to run 5 to 10 parallel tasks you can use eachLimit, where the second argument is the number of parallel tasks you want to execute. If this solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is `async.each` instead of `async.forEach`.
forEach refers to the builtin javascript function, each is part of async.

https://github.com/caolan/async#each

Comment: `async.forEach` is an alias of `async.each`. See [the source](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L213).

Comment: i tried using **each, eachLimit, map, mapLimit, mapseries** but gives me the same output only thing is after 1 or 2 processing No data found is displayed.
Is it possible to run in parallel may be with some limit of 5 or 10 so that it processes faster.

Comment: That's what eachLimit is all about normally. Limiting the concurrency to a predefined amount.

Comment: i used eachLimit but it gives Total : 6 and after that others logs are displayed

Comment: Hi Bert,
eachSeries works it processes one after the other its too slow